# How are list passed as parameter?

Tags: python, list, parameters

Using the following code

```
def test(n): 
    n=n*2 
    print("inside test",n) 

n=[9] 
print("before the call", n) 
test(n) 
print("after the call", n)
```

the ouput is:

```
before the call [9]
inside test [9, 9]
after the call [9]
```

I thought that the passing of list parameters in functions was made by reference and modified the calling parameters.It is not the case here: suprising. I was expecting:

```
before the call [9]
inside test [9, 9]
after the call [9, 9]
```

If I use the `append` method instead of `n=n*2`, the effect is OK.
Can anyone clarify this point, please?

Comment: sorry, I was expecting: before the [9]
inside test [9, 9]
after the call [9,9]

Comment: Try with `n.append(9)`

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Your expectation is same as your output... Are you trying to multiply every element in the list by 2? If so, you'll need to do a list comprehension like this: output = [element * 2 for element in my_list]

Comment: See [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) and [this](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm).

Comment: Sorry my expectation was: 

before the call [9]
inside test [9, 9]
after the call [9, 9]

Comment: In fact I want to understand how really parameters like list are handle in Python?

Comment: @Hana fix the question  with what you actually expect. Will avoid confusion

Comment: Parameters "like lists" are handled in *exactly* the same way as any other parameters. Read those two references I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about mutable or immutable type and value or reference parameter. 
Python pass "reference" but not really ( here for for details : https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/)

```
>>> def update_list(the_list):
    print('got', the_list)
    the_list.append('four')
    print('changed to', the_list)

>>> toto = ["one"]
>>> update_list(toto)
got ['one']
changed to ['one', 'four']
>>> print(toto)
['one', 'four']


>>> def new_list(the_list):
    print('got', the_list)
    the_list = the_list + ["four"]
    print('changed to', the_list)

>>> toto = ["one"]
>>> new_list(toto)
got ['one']
changed to ['one', 'four']
>>> print(toto)
['one']
```

Python documentation :
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference

A similar question : 
[How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

This line `n = n*2`, creates a new local variable `n` inside your `test()` function, that's why the outside one is not changed. Take a look at these examples:

```
>>> def test(n):
...     print(id(n))
...     n = n*2
...     print(id(n))
...     print("inside test", n)
...
>>> def test2(n):
...     print(id(n))
...     n.append(2)
...     print(id(n))
...     print("inside test2", n)
...
>>> n = [9]
>>> id(n)
49744472
>>>
>>> test(n)
49744472
49744752
('inside test', [9, 9])
>>>
>>> test2(n)
49744472
49744472
('inside test2', [9, 2])
```

Inside `test()`, we have 2 different ids: `49744472` for the **param** `n` and `49744752` for **the local variable** `n`. In `test2()` function the same id is printed, which means the same **param** `n` is changed inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

In python, generally it is confusing to refer to arguments being passed to function as either pass by value/pass by reference.

n=[9]

The above statement binds n to a List object containing single element of value 9. (i.e. [9] in this case)

When n = n * 2 
This creates a new List and bound to a variable which is local to the scope of the function.

Comment: Thanks all. I understand that parameters passing is confusing in Python.

Answer (score 0):

In n = n*2 creates a local variable inside test function, return n and assign it to n with the results

```
def test(n): 
    n=n*2 
    print("inside test",n) 
    return n

n=[9] 
print("before the call", n) 
n = test(n) 
print("after the call", n)
```

Output:

```
('before the call', [9])
('inside test', [9, 9])
('after the call', [9, 9])
```